# Is pulseaudio's default nice value (-11) actually ineffective due to autogroup?

Tags: arch-linux, pulseaudio, scheduling, nice, priority

The *pulseaudio* daemon runs with nice level -11 by default, via *rtkit*.

However, I'm noticing choppy audio at times of high cpu load, and decreasing the nice value even further by setting `high-priority = yes` and `nice-level = -16` in *`/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`* has no effect. `realtime-scheduling = yes` and `realtime-priority = 6`, in turn, also appear to have no effect as the default Arch kernel doesn't appear to support realtime scheduling.

After reading answers on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/405092/300053) and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10342470/3258851) (and also [Super User](https://superuser.com/q/805599/358758)) suggesting that, due to [autogrouping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_Fair_Scheduler#Fairer_algorithms), a process' `nice` value is not global, I'm wondering if the nice level used by Pulseaudio by default is rendered ineffective at the end of the day (unless autogrouping is turned off, which is not without it's own concerns).

Does anyone know?